# Flutter Listview when item added scroll position changing

Tags: flutter, dart

First screen is this

[image]

When i add item to list scroll position changing to this

[image]

Here is the ListView

[image]

Comment: why are you using the AlwaysScrollablePhysics - I feel there  some other parent widget the is causing this issue ?